# Proof that $\operatorname{sup}_{n}f_{n}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions $f_{n}: (X, \mathcal{F}) \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$. In my notes, my professor proved $g(x) = \sup_{n}f_{n}(x)$ is measurable just by noticing that:
$$g^{-1}((a,\infty]) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}^{-1}((a,\infty]) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
But why is this enough? I mean, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$ on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, where the topology in this set is defined by the order topology. Equivalently,
$$\mathbb{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}} = \{E \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{R}}: A \cap \mathbb{R} \in \mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\}$$
And it seems to me that (\ref{1}) is implying that $\mathbb{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$ is generated by the sets $\{(a,\infty]: a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but I don't see why is this the case.

Comment: Don't the sets $\{(a, \infty]: a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ form a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$? The $\pi$-system above can generate any open set in $\mathbb{R}$, and every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable union of open intervals.

Comment: Intersecting such sets with complements of such sets gives you left-open right-closed intervals. countable unions of those give you open intervals

Comment: You probably are forgetting that the pre-image of a sigma field is a sigma field, so if you prove that $f$ is "measurable on a basis" then it is "measurable everywhere."